# How can I generate random integers in java?

Tags: java, random

How can I generate random integers and then print them?

I have tried the following code,but it does not compile.

```
    import java.util.Random;
    class Random
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        int num=rand.nextInt(40);
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

Comment: put your code in a `main` method, and give it another name or prefix the classnames.

Comment: rename your class to RandomTest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use unique class names unless you feel like referring to the different `Random`s by their full package titles.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MyRandom {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Random rand = new Random(); 
      int num = rand.nextInt(40);
      System.out.println(num);
   }
}
```

Save the above as `MyRandom.java`, then do a;

```
javac MyRandom.java
java MyRandom
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
  log("Generated : " + randomInt);
}
```